# How do i fix no sequelize instance passed

Tags: sequelize.js

I am trying to create a sequelize database but I am getting the error "No sequelize instance passed" is their anyway to fix this with the posted code thanks in advance

employmentApplication.js

```
    const sequalize = require('../config/connection')
const {Model, DataTypes} = require('sequelize')

class employmentApplication extends Model {}

employmentApplication.init(
    {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: false,
        freezeTableName: true,
        underscored: true
    }
)

module.exports = employmentApplication
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const sequalize = require('./config/connection')


const routes = require('./routes')
// const routes = require('./routes/apiRoutes')
const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(routes)
// app.use('/employmentApplication', routes)
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

sequalize.sync({ force: false }).then(() => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('now listening'))
})
```

connection.js

```
const Sequalize = require('sequelize')
    
require('dotenv').config()

const sequalize = new Sequalize('applicants', 'username', 'password', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mysql',
    port: 3306
})

module.exports = sequalize
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't pass Sequelize instance to a model `init` method:

```js
mploymentApplication.init(
    {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: false,
        freezeTableName: true,
        underscored: true,
        sequelize // here should be a sequelize instance created beforehand
    }
)
```

See [Creating a model using classes](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html#extending--a-href-----class-src-model-js-model-html--model--a-)